# How can I integrate Authorize.net to receive paypal payments in Magento?

Tags: magento, paypal, payment, authorize.net

I want to receive paypal payments by using Authorize.net. In Authorize.net, there is an option of "Digital Payment Solution" where you can enable paypal or visa checkout. But I can not see anychange in my Magento Authorize.net payment details. Can somebody help me to receive payments in authorize.net?

Comment: This might be a little better suited for magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: These are relatively new integrations from Authorize.Net, so they would need to be added to the payment module.